# Generic enumeration for finite n-uple of naturals.

Tags: combinatorics

For programming exercises, I'm finding myself with problems where I should find:

$$f: \{1, 2, \cdots, n_1 \times n_2\times \cdots \times n_k\} \rightarrow \{1, 2, \cdots, n_1 \} \times \{1, 2, \cdots, n_2 \}\times \cdots \times \{1, 2, \cdots, n_k \}$$

With $f$ a bijective function. The problem is to have an efficient and elegant way of computing this function for a generic dimension $k$ of the image.

Example for $n_1 = 2$, $n_2=2$, $k=2$:

$f(1) = (1,1)$

$f(2) = (2,1)$

$f(3) = (1,2)$

$f(4) = (2,2)$

In general, if all $n_k$ are equal, this is simple (akin to a base conversion), but I haven't found a method to do this for arbitrary different values for each $n_k$.

Doing this in a straightforward or at worse recursive manner would make much of my coding a lot easier.

Comment: if you assume $n_1\geq n_2\geq \cdots \geq n_k$ you can do the same while algorithm no? Can you do this? This would increase the complexity to $O(n\cdot log(n))$.

Comment: This is called *unranking*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, if you have $0\leq s\leq n_1\times \cdots \times n_k-1$ then you can give write $s$ as $$s=n_1(n_2(n_3(\cdots (n_{k-1}r_k+r_{k-1})+r_3)+r_2)+r_1,$$ where $0\leq r_i< n_i$ in such a way that the initial inequality is satisfied. In this way, the algorithm is just $$s\mapsto ((s \pmod {n_1})+1,(\left \lfloor \frac{s}{n_1}\right \rfloor \pmod {n_2})+1,(\left \lfloor \lfloor s/n_1\right \rfloor /n_2\rfloor  \pmod {n_3})+1,\cdots , \left (\lfloor \cdots \lfloor \lfloor s/n_1\rfloor/n_2\rfloor \cdots \rfloor /n_{k-1}\rfloor \right )+1).$$
That is $r_i$ is obtained by mod out by $n_i$ after successfully divide $s$ by the $n_1, \cdots , n_{i-1}$ numbers. If you are worried that it does not work, is not hard to show by induction that this is bijection.
**Comment:** My earlier comment was just me thinking that you would end up having a non one-to-one map in the base conversion (which is not true, you do **not** need $n_1\geq n_2\geq \cdots \geq n_k$).

Comment: Reminds me of Horner's rule, quite cool!